# Move dataset to another region bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, publish-subscribe, dataflow

I want to move a dataset to another region but there are some pubsub subscriptions with dataflow templates loading the tables within the dataset. How can I do this without interrupting the dataflow jobs? Or interrupt them as little as possible.

Is it possible to do this in these steps?:

1. Create a temporary dataset with a temporary name in a new region
2. Copy original dataset to the temporary dataset
3. Delete old original dataset
4. Create a new dataset with the original name in the new region
5. Copy temporary dataset the new dataset with the original dataset

Im open for suggestions :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [copy dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets) feature in preview for now. One interesting feature is the cross region copy available with the feature.

You can perform the same process but easier!

About your Dataflow pipeline, I think it won't work. Indeed, the location is an important information when you write to BigQuery. Have a try, but I'm pretty sure that you have to update it.